# How to delete rows where more than 1 column matches another table?

Tags: sql, db2

I have two tables. One (let's call it table1) looks a bit like this:

```
account_number | offer_code
---------------|-----------
1              | 123
1              | 456
2              | 123
```

The other table (let's call it table2) looks a bit like this:

```
account_number | offer_code
---------------|-----------
1              | 123
```

I want to delete all rows from table1 where the account_number AND the offer_code match a row in table2. So afterwards table1 would look like this:

```
account_number | offer_code
---------------|-----------
1              | 456
2              | 123
```

I've tried the following, but it doesn't run:

```
DELETE  
FROM    TABLE1 A
INNER JOIN
        TABLE2 B
ON      A.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = B.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
AND     A.OFFER_CODE = B.OFFER_CODE
;
```

I've also tried the following. It seems to run, but the sheer volume of data in both tables (65.5m rows in table1 and 9m in table2) mean it takes an impractically long time to do so (I was forced to kill the query after 3 hours).

```
DELETE
FROM    TABLE1
WHERE   CONCAT(ACCOUNT_NUMBER, OFFER_CODE) IN
        (
        SELECT  CONCAT(ACCOUNT_NUMBER, OFFER_CODE)
        FROM    TABLE2
        )
;
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to accomplish this efficiently please?

Comment: This is very basic question. Try the `EXISTS` predicate.

Answer (score 0):

Databases do not like update and delete processes. They are exhausting. Depending on your application(carefully check this out!!!) you can try this:

```
create table table1_tmp
select * from table1
minus
select * from table2;

alter table table1 rename to table1_tmp2;
alter table table1_tmp rename to table1;
```